# Linq query to fill complex model?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to do something I'm not sure LINQ can do  -but let's try!
I have 2 classes; one is a list structure for the other:

```
public class1 {
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set;}
    public List<class2> subcat {get; set;}
}
public class2 {
    public int Value {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

Is it possible to fill such structure with LINQ?  Something like:

```
return (from r in results 
    from sub in subresults.Where(sub => sub.id == r.subid).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new class1  {
        id = r.id,
        title = r.title,
        subcat = [GET TWO COLUMNS FROM 'SUB' INTO THIS]
    }).ToList()
```

Is this possible? I'd hate to have to build them manually by using nested loops, etc.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeap, you can reduce this complex query by using Join() ... however, i think it doesn't reduce too much because of you have to build query of creation class1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
return (from r in results 
    select new class1  {
        id = r.id,
        title = r.title,
        subcat = (from sub in subresults
                 where sub.id == r.subid
                 select new class2 { Value = sub.Value, Text = sub.Text }).ToList()

    }).ToList()
```

Comment: i think that'll work!  - I'll try it now. Meanwhile, is the select going to run for every record or is it rendered as a subquery (one select statement to, one recordset back)?

Comment: The latter. This is a select N+1 (problem).

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but i'm now getting an error - which disappears if i remove the "subcat = (from...).ToList() field:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BluArcCrm.ViewModels.Contact_Index_GroupFolders] ToList[Contact_Index_GroupFolders](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BluArcCrm.ViewModels.Contact_Index_GroupFolders])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Then don't make a `List`, just keep the `IEnumerable`. If you have to make a list check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930925/linq-to-entities-projection-of-nested-list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation property to load results and subresults in one query.

```
from r in results
select new class1  {
    id = r.id,
    title = r.title,
    subcat = r.Subresults.Select(sr =>
             new class2 { Value = sr.Value, Text = sr.Text })
```

...assuming that the navigation property `result.Subresults` exists or otherwise can be created for convenience.

AutoMapper could also be useful here. If yo define two mappings (`result => class1`, `subresult => class2`) it will load the nested collection automatically.