# How to convert a child collection of domain objects to a collection of custom objects using Entity Framework and ASP.NET Web API (Visual Basic)?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have the following domain classes in my model automatically generated from my database:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property lastName As String
    Public Property addresses As ICollection(Of Address) = New HashSet(Of Address)()
End Class

Public Class Address
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property personId As Integer
    Public Property addressLine As String
End Class
```

And I created the following custom DTO classes to represent the data passed on to the user:

```
Public Class PersonDTO
    Public Property lastName As String
    Public Property addresses As ICollection(Of AddressDTO) = New HashSet(Of AddressDTO)()
End Class

Public Class AddressDTO
    Public Property addressLine As String
End Class
```

I'd like to do the following to query the database and return a collection of PersonDTO objects, each with its collection of AddressDTO objects:

```
Using db as New DatabaseContext()

    Dim people As IQueryable(Of PersonDTO) =
        db.Persons.Include("addresses")
        .Select(Function(p) New PersonDTO With
        {
            .lastName = p.lastName,
            .addresses = p.addresses.Select(Function(a) New AddressDTO With {.addressLine = a.addressLine}).ToList()
        })

End Using
```

For some reason, this query compiles and doesn't throw any exceptions when executed, but no data is returned and in fact my client receives a server 500 error when it runs. However, it works just fine if I change the code to this (which exposes the domain object, which I'd prefer not to do):

```
Public Class PersonDTO
    Public Property lastName As String
    Public Property addresses As ICollection(Of Address) = New HashSet(Of Address)()
End Class

Using db as New DatabaseContext()

    Dim people As IQueryable(Of PersonDTO) =
        db.Persons.Include("addresses")
        .Select(Function(p) New PersonDTO With
        {
            .lastName = p.lastName,
            .addresses = p.addresses
        })

End Using
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does it make any difference when you end the statement with .ToList()?

Comment: it would help if you tell us the error

Comment: There is no error when debugging, it steps through the query just fine. The problem is that it doesn't return any data and the Web API generates a 500 HTTP response code. One thing I noticed while debugging is that when stepping through the code, the IQueryable object "disappears" once it hits that inner select on address DTOs. By that I mean, before then, I can read the object's properties in the debugger, but once it hits the inner select, suddenly the debugger says it's either not declared or I don't have access to view it's properties. Very weird...

Comment: Ruard van Elbirg- I haven't tried doing ToList on the entire query...I'll try that when I get a chance and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Try not to return an `IQueryable` inside a `using` block...just return a list of the `DTO` classes by using a `.ToList()` after casting to DTO class....Since I believe it is an issue of context disposition before the query actually returns the result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I was able to find the answer here:

[LINQ to Entities projection of nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930925/linq-to-entities-projection-of-nested-list)

I had to project the nested collection of DTOs as a property of an anonymous class. This way, it could keep it as an IQueryable rather than actualizing it as a list. Then, I could call ToListAsync to query the database in one go and then use LINQ to objects to put the AddressDTO collection into the PersonDTO. The following code worked for me:

```
Using db as New DatabaseContext()

    Dim anonymousPersonDTOList =
         db.Persons.Include("addresses")
         .Select(Function(p) New With
            {
                .pDTO = New PersonDTO With
                    {
                        .lastName = p.lastName
                    },
                .addresses = p.addresses.Select(Function(a) New AddressDTO With
                    {
                        .addressLine = a.addressLine
                    })
            }).ToListAsync()

    Dim personDTOList as IEnumerable(Of PersonDTO) =
        anonymousPersonDTOList.Select(
            Function(p)
                p.pDTO.addresses = p.addresses.ToList()
                Return p.pDTO
            End Function)

    Return personDTOList

End Using
```